# invalid_grant when try New Apple ID Sign In

Tags: android, ios, laravel, curl

I keep getting an invalid_grant error on trying to get an oAuth token from Apple in https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token api

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. What was causing the issue was that the app was returning me a base64 encoded authorization code instead of utf8 encoded one. Once we changed this the api responded successfully.

Other issues I have seen related to the problem are.

1. Using a service Id based client_secret instead of App Id based one. client_secret generated using service Id should only be used for logging into a website registered under the app. For code generated from native apps we have to use App Id based client_secret.
2. Reusing an authorization code or using it too late. If you make a request with an authorization code and it failed, the code is consumed. You cannot reuse it again. Re generate a new code and start again. Also I have seen people reporting that the code only has a validity of 5 minutes (not sure about this though).